# UITabBarController tabbar item shows only when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

My project is in Xcode 5.0.2 and since I've upgraded to OS X 10.10 I can't use Xcode 5.0.2 now and I need to use Xcode 6 but my problem is my tabbar items in xib file only shows when they're selected(Once selected the image with load and will not hide when unselected).here's the screenshot of it on first load.

Note: I'm using an old UITabBarController usign xib

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is only [self setNeedsToDisplay] :D My layout is not updating. Thanks for the help guys :D

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController of every tab add the below code with there respective title and image.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self)
 {
    self.tabBarItem.title = @"Dashboard";
    self.tabBarItem.image  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashBoard"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    self.tabBarItem.selectedImage=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashBoardSelect"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
 }
return self;
}
```

Comment: I can't apply your solution because I'm using it in my Appdelegate